# Proper way of check if the resource exist in GCP

Tags: linux, bash, grep, gcloud

Probably some dev or tech people may assume that this question is duplicated. But my question is more about following the best practices and getting DRY bash scripting. I have a question about how to check properly if any request was created in GCP using `gcloud` command.

I am executing the following command to create for example X project

```
gcloud projects create fsadykov-test
```

After that command I would like to use until command to verify if the project is ready to use

```
until gcloud projects list | grep "$GCP_PROJECT_TO_CREATE" &> /dev/null; do
  logger "The Google is preparing the project <$GCP_PROJECT_TO_CREATE> please wait!" "info" && sleep 10
done
```

But the problem is `&>` not working for a reason or I am missing something here it is printing the following output

```
Listed 0 items.
Preparing the project <fsadykov-1032123124123123> please wait!
Listed 0 items.
Preparing the project <fsadykov-1032123124123123> please wait!
Listed 0 items.
Preparing the project <fsadykov-1032123124123123> please wait!
Listed 0 items.
Preparing the project <fsadykov-1032123124123123> please wait!
Listed 0 items.
Preparing the project <fsadykov-1032123124123123> please wait!
Listed 0 items.
Preparing the project <fsadykov-1032123124123123> please wait!
```

I was expecting following output

```
Preparing the project <fsadykov-1032123124123123> please wait!
Preparing the project <fsadykov-1032123124123123> please wait!
Preparing the project <fsadykov-1032123124123123> please wait!
Preparing the project <fsadykov-1032123124123123> please wait!
```

I did research about this and found the following ticket but not working for me
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36076836?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** You don't need to `until gcloud projects create` because successful completion of `gcloud projects create` means that the project was created (and is ready).

---

`gcloud` commands are synchronous.

A return code of `0` indicates that the command completed without error.

If `gcloud projects create` completes with a return code of `0`, the project is created.

Rather than pipe the output of list commands e.g. `gcloud projects list` to `grep`, it's generally better to describe the specific resource, e.g. `gcloud projects describe`.

`gcloud` supports [filtering and formatting](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/it-ops/filtering-and-formatting-fun-with) to process the results of commands. Rather than pipe the results of e.g. `gcloud projects describe` to `grep` to search a set of results for one instance, you can `--filter` e.g. lists for a specific instance by a specific property.

When `gcloud` commands take an extended time, the commands (even though still synchronous) return long-running operations. The user must then interrogate the operation awaiting the underlying resource(s)' continued pending, successful completion, or even failure.

Lastly, some `gcloud` commands accept an `--async` flag. In this case, without the flag, the command will block until the underlying operation completes (or fails), with the flag, an operation will be returned immediately.